# How can I get the names of rows in a data.table satisfying a regex condition?

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have a data.table as follows:

```
data=data.table(dates=c('04 SEPTEMBER 2018', '05 APR 2018', '7/10/2018'), DT = c('21/07/2010', '3 04 2018', '16 DEC 2018'), amounts = c(21,37,49))
```

And I would like the names of rows in a data.table satisfying the following grep condition

```
grepl("^[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}",x)
```

so that I can find rows with dates fulfilling specific date formats. As you can see, both columns `dates` and `DT` contain date formats. I do not want to refer to a specific column in the code. I would just like to pick rows containing characters matching the above grep pattern.

I expect the correct code to return `c(2,3)` since those rows contain the required strings. How can I get the answer that I expect?

Comment: Try `which(grepl("^[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}", data$dates))` or `grep("^[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}", data$dates)`

Comment: I'd prefer to get the names without specifically referring to specific column names. I'm assuming I won't know the name of the column that contains dates.

Comment: That is a completely different question. In your attempt yu too refer to the column name `dates`

Comment: I'll make the necessary edit

Comment: Your question is still very vague. How would we know the column? Are all the other columns numeric and the `date` character? Is it always at a specific position in the dataset? Please try and be explicit. Unless you want to apply that to every column...??

Comment: The premise of the question is incorrect. `data.table` objects do NOT  have rownames. You could force it to be a dataframe and then extract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lapply()`  to identity which columns matches the regexpr. Since `lapply()` outputs a list, use `` Reduce(`|`, ...) `` to verify whether at least one of the columns per row satisfy the regexpr condition:

```
data[
  data[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x) grepl("^[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}",x)))], 
  ]
```

Result:

```
> data[
+   data[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x) grepl("^[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}",x)))], 
+   ]
         dates amounts
1: 05 APR 2018      37
2: 16 DEC 2018      49
```

#### Update

To get the indices of the rows for which there is a match (for any column): Use `sapply()` to get a matrix with the cells indicating whether the match was successful. Then use `rowSums(...) > 0` to consolidate it into a single vector with values of `TRUE` (at least one cell in the row has a successful match) or `FALSE` (no matches at all). Wrap it all in `which()` to display the row indices.

Result:

```
> which(rowSums(sapply(data,function(x) grepl("^[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}",x))) > 0)
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not return the row indices 2 and 3, which are the solutions

Comment: Does it? In which column of the result? You result appears to be the rows themselves and not their indices

Comment: It returns rows 2 and 3, yes. What are you exactly looking for? The actual index "2" and "3"?

Comment: I'm getting c(1,2) instead of c(2,3)

Comment: OK, so you want the output to be `"2" "3"`? It returns the rows that match the regex. Not sure if you want the row index to be returned or the rows.

Comment: See this: `which(rowSums(sapply(data,function(x) grepl("^[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}",x))) > 0)`. If that works for you, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

an other data.table approach:

```
ans <- melt( transpose(data), 
             id.vars = NULL, 
             measure.vars = patterns("^V"), 
             variable.name = "row" )
ans <- ans[ grepl("^[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}", value), ]
ans[, row := gsub("V", "", row)]
```

> ```
>     row       value
>  1:   2 05 APR 2018
>  2:   3 16 DEC 2018
> ```

**update**

```
data[ seq.int(.N) %in% ans$row, ]
```

> ```
>           dates          DT amounts
>  1: 05 APR 2018   3 04 2018      37
>  2:   7/10/2018 16 DEC 2018      49
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to get just the rows?

Comment: Apologies, I meant just the row names without the actual rows...sorry that's my mistake

Comment: `data.table` does not support rownames (is what I was always told).

Comment: If you just want the rownumbers, use `ans$row`... it returns `c("2","3")`